# Acces groovy var in sh in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using enviroment variable ARTIFACT_VERSION, and want to put it in shell script

```
 sh "wget -q http://nexus.com/$polygon/$env.ARTIFACT_VERSION/$polygon-$env.ARTIFACT_VERSION.zip"
```

And got this errors

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.lang.String zip
```

And if I input var with this style `${env.ARTIFACT_VERSION}`
I get in output result like I am using \n (but version input is correct)

```
 wget -q http://nexus.com/polygon/myversion
/polygon-myversion
.zip
```

The link is correct when i used it without vars - all is ok

Answer (score 0):

myversion parameter was getting as a result from grep command
and it had \n at the end